# How to update table column using array and for loop in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

```
for ($key=0; $key < count($_POST['marks']); $key++) {

            $from_marks = $_POST['from'][$key];
            $get_marks = $_POST['marks'][$key];

            //echo $from_marks." ";
            if($get_marks > $from_marks){
                // header("location: ../../pages/marks.php?over=err");
                // break;

                echo "Cant add more marks <br/>";

            }
            else{
                echo $get_marks."<br/>";

                $update_marks_query = $db->prepare(
                    "UPDATE sc_marks SET get_marks='"
                    .$get_marks
                    ."' WHERE _sid='$sc_foreign_id' AND exam_type='$select_exam_type' ");
                $update_marks_query -> execute();
            }
}
```

The issue is occurred when I execute the code, I got the last fetched value in each rows of the table.

Data result after update:

[image: Data result after update]

Comment: The fact that all your rows end up containing the same data would suggest that the `WHERE` clause of your `UPDATE` statement always matches every row in the table. I can't really give a more accurate answer without knowing where and how the used variables `$sc_foreign_id` and `$select_exam_type` are defined, and what kind of data their associated fields contain in the database.

Comment: By the way, you should prepare your update statement before the `for` loop `$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE sc_marks SET get_marks=? WHERE _sid=? AND exam_type=?");` and then attach the parameters during each iteration with `$query->execute($get_marks, $sc_foreign_id, $select_exam_type);`. Your current approach is a security risk, apart from being less efficient than it could be. Read about [SQL injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    <?php
    include "./connection/config.php";

    if(isset($_POST['btn_update_marks'])){

        $sc_foreign_id = $_POST['sc_foreign_id'];
        $select_exam_type = $_POST['select_exam_type'];

        for($key=0; $key<count($_POST['marks']); $key++){

            $from_marks = $_POST['from'][$key];
            $get_marks = $_POST['marks'][$key];

            echo $from_marks." ";


            if($get_marks > $from_marks){
                // header("location: ../../pages/marks.php?over=err");
                // break;

                echo "Marks Vadhu Chhe <br/>";

            }
            else{
                echo $get_marks."<br/>";

                $update_marks_query = $db->query("UPDATE sc_marks SET get_marks='".$get_marks."' WHERE _sid='$sc_foreign_id' AND exam_type='$select_exam_type' ");
            }
            // else{
                // $update_marks_query = $db->prepare("UPDATE sc_marks SET get_marks='$get_marks' WHERE _sid='$sc_foreign_id' ");
                // $update_done = $update_marks_query -> execute();
            // }
        }

        // if($update_done){
            // echo "Successfully Updated";
            // header("location: ../../pages/marks.php?add-marks=yes");
        // }
        // else{
            // echo "Error";
            // header("location: ../../pages/marks.php?add-marks=error");
        // }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to prepare your update statement before the for loop

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE sc_marks SET get_marks=? WHERE _sid=? AND exam_type=?");

for ($key=0; $key < count($_POST['marks']); $key++) {

            $from_marks = $_POST['from'][$key]; //add some validation here
            $get_marks = $_POST['marks'][$key]; //e.G with regex

            //echo $from_marks." ";
            if($get_marks > $from_marks){
                // header("location: ../../pages/marks.php?over=err");
                // break;

                echo "Cant add more marks <br/>";

            }
            else{
                echo $get_marks."<br/>";

                $query->execute($get_marks, $sc_foreign_id, $select_exam_type); 

            }
}

//Then attach the parameters during each iteration within the loop
```

Your current approach is a security risk, apart from being less efficient than it could be. Read about SQL injection.